# How to detect Fingersize with IOS?

Tags: ios, multi-touch

Is it possible to detect the fingersize in an IOS Application?
I've read in the documentation:

> Notes: A finger on the screen affords a much different level of
>   precision than a mouse pointer. When a user touches the screen, the
>   area of contact is actually elliptical and tends to be offset below
>   the point where the user thinks he or she touched. This “contact
>   patch” also varies in size and shape based on which finger is touching
>   the screen, the size of the finger, the pressure of the finger on the
>   screen, the orientation of the finger, and other factors. The
>   underlying Multi-Touch system analyzes all of this information for you
>   and computes a single touch point.

Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20121120152010/http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html

So, does that mean theres no possibility with the SDK to detect the physical fingersize? What I want to accomplish: I need virtual "buttons" in my OpenGL ES Application. And if someone hold the iPhone like a gamepad, he will probalbly use one finger for two buttons (rolling off the thumb). I hope its understandable what I mean...

Any ideas?

Comment: You could just handle `(void)touchesMoved: (NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` and check the `locationInView` of the given touches. So you would have one gamepad view/area and check which part is hit/covered on touchesMoved.

Comment: But I can retrieve only one CGPoint from locationInView, and not for both button positions. So iOS seems to detect only one "blob" at all (not both - a big thumb isn't detected as 2 touches)...

Comment: You could still an area within the gamepad view which would be valid for both buttons - think of the buttons intersecting each others.

Comment: There is a draft in W3C that requires OS exposes those properties to developer. [docs](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webevents/raw-file/default/touchevents.html#widl-Touch-radiusX). Hopefully in future Safari implements that and we can use it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@fichek is right, there is no regular way to get the size of fingertips.

However, I had used a 'strange' way in my previous project to do it, and it just works ;-)

1.Tell our user to put two fingers on the screen together, the closer the better(like the two-finger scrolling gesture on Mac):
[image]

2.Get the two **CGPoints** from **UITouches** in the **touchesBegan:withEvent:** method;

3.Now we have CGPoint **fingertip1center** and **fingertip2center**, so:

```
float fingertip_Diameter=fabsf(fingertip1center.x-fingertip2center.x);
```

4.The fingers are really close and we may ignore the tiny difference in width , so **dX == the real width** of a singel finger.

5.The width(dX) and the fingertipsize are proportional, we can simply use

`float fingertip_Size=M_PI*(dX/2)*(dX/2);`

or find a better algorithm to meet your needs ;-)

6.Once we got the size (actually we only care about the diameter), its easy to implement a method to optimize touching by testing various surrounded points, e.g.:

```
#define kTestLevelOne 5 //Testing 5 points:origin,left,right,up,down
#define kTestLevelTwo 9 //And the other 4 corners
-(BOOL)testSurroundingPoints:(CGPoint *)pt
{
   float prob_x[kTestLevelTwo]={0,-dX/2,dX/2,0,0,-dX/2,-dX/2,dX/2,dX/2};
   float prob_y[kTestLevelTwo]={0,0,0,dX/2,-dX/2,dX/2,-dX/2,dX/2,-dX/2};

   for(int i=0;i<kTestLevelTwo;i++)
   {
      if([self gotItAtX:pt.x+prob_x[i] andY:pt.y+prob_y[i]]==YES)
       {
           NSLog(@"Got It!");
           Return YES;
           //Or break; We don't need to try more points!
       }
   }
   return NO;
}
```

Hope these can help!

Yichao Peak Ji

Answer (score 5):

Actually, there's a way to get the touch radius:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches 
      withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGFloat touchSize = [[touch valueForKey:@"pathMajorRadius"] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"touch size is %.2f", touchSize);
}
```

Source:
http://easyplace.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/how-to-detect-touch-size-in-ios/

Answer (score 2):

iOS does all sorts of finger size/angle/location calculation behind the scenes, so there is no way to detect anything but the computed location of a touch. However, that's more than enough info for you to know which part of gamepad the finger is on.

As @marcus mentioned, you should implement the touchesMoved:withEvent: method and check for touch's location to determine if it's over left/right/top/bottom/center or whatever "buttons" you want to have.